# vim : The term 'vim' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet?

Tags: laravel, vim

I'm following a tutorial on Laravel. I've never used it before. The tutorial say I should use create a file with `vim database/database.sql` but when I do I get the error:

```
vim : The term 'vim' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ vim
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (vim:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I've tried to install vim from vim.org but don't know if this is right.
Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm using windows 10.

Comment: What Operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 10

Comment: You should install it from [here](https://github.com/vim/vim-win32-installer/releases/download/v8.2.2825/gvim_8.2.2825_x86_signed.exe) and in installation process, check "create .bat files for command line use"

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In addition to installing Vim from vim.org, you also need to make sure it's added to $PATH in order to use it from the command line without using the full path.
On Windows, you can do this with

Control Panel -> System -> Edit the system environment variables -> Click Environment Variables -> Find the `PATH` variable -> Click "edit" -> Check if Vim is here, otherwise  click "new" -> Click "browse" -> Navigate to the Vim executable that you installed

After vim has been added to `PATH`, you should be able to use it from the command line.
You will need to close and re-open Cmd/PowerShell.

Answer (score 8):

In my case resetting/adding environment variable for VIM didn't help.

I managed to resolve this issue installing **[Chocolatey Windows Package Manager](https://chocolatey.org/install#individual)**.

In Powershell with admin rights run:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://community.chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
```

then:
`choco install vim` and `refreshenv`

Your Vim is ready to run within Powershell.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Windows and you didn't change the installation path when installing vim, these are the steps to perform:

1. Press `Ctrl`+`R` to open the Run command window
2. Type `sysdm.cpl` to open the System Properties window
   [image]
3. Click the *Advanced* tab
4. Click *Environment Variables...* button
   [image]
5. Choose either *User variable for [Your user name]* or *System variables*, click the row with `Path` variable
6. Click *Browse...* to find the Vim executable. If the version of vim installed is 8.2.XXXX, it should be located at *C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim82*, else change the `vim82` into the appropriate folder name where your *gvim.exe* is located at.

Comment: exact same issue with neovim, have to manual add the `bin` path to environment. Took for granted that the installation msi will do that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply try: `start vim yourFileName`

Answer (score -4):

I believe you basically want to open a sql file. You can open it with any editor.
You can just execute the below commands in your command prompt :

```
cd database
notepad database.sql
```

If working with vim is essential in your case, then I would suggest installing gvim for your windows.

Comment: I don't enough about vim yet. Looks like they (in the tut) just used it to create the file. I tried to download gvim from `vim.org` but the same error still occurred. I will try again, but I don't think it was as necessary as I first thought. Thank you for the help anyway!